# Array or ObjectType as an argument GraphQL rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, arguments

I need to pass an array of `ids` or an array of objects. How can I pass it?

```
field :deleteDispatches, Types::DispatchType do
  argument :route_id, !types.ID
  argument :dispatches_id, ![types.ID] #doesn't work
  argument :dispatches, [Types::DispatchType] #doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass an array of `ids` using this code `argument :dispatches_id, !types[types.ID]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need input object for a Dispatch e.g. `Inputs::DispatchInput`

```
field :deleteDispatches, Types::DispatchType do
  argument :route_id, !types.ID
  argument :dispatches_id, !types[types.ID]
  argument :dispatches, types[Inputs::DispatchInput]
```

Inputs::DispatchInput:

```
# inputs/dispatch_input.rb
module Inputs
  class FilterInput < Types::BaseInputObject
    argument :id, Int, required: true
    argument :name, String, required: false
  end
end
```